# PHP custom regex

Tags: php, regex

I've written this regex to check for valid emails: `/^[-a-z0-9._]+@[-a-z0-9._]+\.+[a-z]{2,6}$/i`

I want it to work for emails like `name1+name2@domaine.com`

How can I fix this regex?

Comment: That regular expression has countless other problems as well.

Comment: closevoting as "Too Localized", unless you point out why you have to use your own regex instead of using one of the 3700+ solutions to validate emails given in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=validate+email+php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First part

```
[-a-z0-9._]+
```

does not accept right now plus sign. Expand it:

```
[-+a-z0-9._]+
```

Answer (score 3):

I Have a simpler solution.

```
if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALID_EMAIL))
{
    //true
}
```

this would be sufficient in most cases, this actually runs an regular check in C which in turn would be faster but if you wish to have control over the reg-ex in your application then the regex below is what's used for this check:

```
/^((\\\"[^\\\"\\f\\n\\r\\t\\b]+\\\")|([\\w\\!\\#\\$\\%\\&\\'\\*\\+\\-\\~\\/\\^\\`\\|\\{\\}\\=\\?]+(\\.[\\w\\!\\#\\$\\%\\&\\'\\*\\+\\-\\~\\/\\^\\`\\|\\{\\}\\=\\?]+)*))@((\\[(((25[0-5])|(2[0-4][0-9])|([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))\\.((25[0-5])|(2[0-4][0-9])|([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))\\.((25[0-5])|(2[0-4][0-9])|([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))\\.((25[0-5])|(2[0-4][0-9])|([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])))\\])|(((25[0-5])|(2[0-4][0-9])|([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))\\.((25[0-5])|(2[0-4][0-9])|([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))\\.((25[0-5])|(2[0-4][0-9])|([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))\\.((25[0-5])|(2[0-4][0-9])|([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])))|((([A-Za-z0-9\\-])+\\.)+[A-Za-z\\-]+))$/D
```

Another tip i will give you is that a user may enter an email address such as: **invalid@dontexists.com** which would then bypass your checks for a valid email, if you wan't to make sure that **dontexists.com** is running an email server is do:

```
$has_mx_server = (bool)checkdnsrr($domain,"MX");
```

if the domain has a registered MX Record the chances of the email being faked is reduced by a good chunk.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/^[-a-z0-9._+]+@[-a-z0-9._]+\.+[a-z]{2,6}$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the + inside the braces and escape it with a backslash

```
/^[-a-z0-9._\+]+@[-a-z0-9._]+\.+[a-z]{2,6}$/i
```

"+" is a meta character meaning to search for 1 or more occurrence, therefore, to search for the actual character, it must be escaped.